# VB.NET : Datacolumn DateTime set NullValue

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

I have a vb.net application with some datasets. In my sql database, i have a `datetime` type that i would like to modify in my script. This field is Nullable in my database.

So, I create a DataColumn to represent this which is configure like that :

[image]

My Problem : I would like to set the value of `MyDate` to Null. For this, I need to set the field "NullValue" to (Empty) or (Nothing) (anything else that (Throw exception)). When I set this field to another thing, I just get 'Property value is not valid'.

Do you know how I could set a NullValue to `MyDate`?